# Edit text bottom line looks black in android 4.1

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have put an edit text which has a tint color as white. But it looks black in android above 4.0 devices till lollipop.

I searched for this and got solutions as apply background color as white.

But I have another layout from which the edit text belongs which has dark blue color, so if I apply background color as white whole edit text looks white on that dark blue layout.

What can I do for this now?

Layout :

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/purple_bg"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:id="@+id/editTextOrderItem"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
        android:drawableTint="#ffffff"
        android:hint="Type here..."
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageViewSearch"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageViewSearch"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewSearch"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_search"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="06dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

color.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#eeeeee</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#3e3e3e</color>
    <color name="black">#747474</color>
    <color name="drawerBacground">#e6f7fd</color>
    <color name="themetextcolor">#009688</color>
    <color name="darktextcolor">#000000</color>
    <color name="lighttextcolor">#ACABAC</color>
    <color name="activity_bg_color">#D9E7E4</color>
    <color name="activity_footer_color">#37b0a0</color>
    <color name="btn_text">#b3ffffff</color>
    <color name="seperator">#dedede</color>
    <color name="accent">#00B0FF</color>
</resources>
```

Please help, thank you..

EDIT:

I tried to add new theme and put it in activity in manifest, but did not help.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Manifest :

```
     <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2"
        />
```

Comment: Add this line in color.xml file. `<color name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</color>`

Comment: And show your color.xml file.

Comment: Replace color- colorAccent in color.xml with this - <color name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</color>. It will help you.

Comment: added color.xml file. But now the issue is, in another activity I want edit text bottom line as blue so I have put blue color ass accent color. @ChiragSavsani

Comment: Please check my comment for ChiragSavsani. @Shane

Comment: Then you have to create two  drawable file with bottom view colour one with white colour and another with blue colour.

Comment: can you please show an example? @Shane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `drawable` resource xml file (your requirement is only to have a bottom stroke)

Set given`drawable` as the background of the `editText` then you can add the background color you need + bottom line you need with a color

**Explain:**

This is a resource  `drawable`
`dashGap` & `dashWidth` is for doted/broken lines (remove them if you do *not* need dashes)

`android:top`  -> you can give *minus* sizes to the `views` that you *don't* need to  display.(here your requirement is to show only bottom line so top,right & left lines of the item has given -2dp )

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FFF" />  <-- background color here
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="-2dp" android:right="-2dp" android:left="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:dashGap="10px"
                android:dashWidth="10px"
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ababb2"  <-- bottom line color here /> 
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: its showing dotted line below edit text I want plain white line

Comment: @Sid remove dash gaps and add color ="#FFF" in that stroke

Answer (score 1):

you can set different different color accent at activity in your manifest file.

```
<color name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</color>
```

Comment: This is my style that contain color, i will use this style at my activity.

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/side_bar_color</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/side_bar_color</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/side_bar_color</item>
    </style>

as theme on my activity...

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"